Magento 2 API (Customer) Enable / Disable
Good Day,
I am writing a python script to update customer information, I have managed to update the mobile number etc from the customers, but I am struggling to enable / disable a customer via API, can anyone guide me on how to enable / disable a customer?
Here is my code that I use to update the current customer.
update_customer_mobile_url = f"https://xxxxxxxxx/rest/V1/customers/{customer_id}"
                update_customer_mobile_data = {
                    "customer": {
                        "id": customer_id,
                        "email": email,
                        "firstname": firstname,
                        "lastname": lastname,
                        "store_id": store_id,
                        "website_id": website_id,
                        "custom_attributes": [
                            {
                                "attribute_code": "customer_mobile",
                                "value": new_mobile_and_phone_number,
                            },
                        ],
                        "extension_attributes": {
                            "company_attributes": {
                                "status": updated_status
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

As you can see, when I am trying to update status from 0 to 1, I get the below error message:
{"message":"You cannot update the requested attribute. Row ID: %fieldName = %fieldValue.","parameters":{"fieldName":"companyId","fieldValue":0}}

I use method PUT to update.
When I remove extension_attributes then the mobile number is updated correctly but the company status remains unchanged, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
